# Disabling connection to ELPA repository

Tags: emacs, elpa

Is it possible at startup to disable the connection to the ELPA repositories?

I have

```
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t))
```

in my init.el and every time I start emacs, it does connect to the repositories. I would prefer to do that manually time to time.

Comment: None of these lines will make it connect to a repository.

Comment: Thanks to you I found the culprit: it's package-spec.el

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept the answer, so the question is removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `package-spec.el` package makes the connection happen.

Comment: I removed it form my setup. I'm installing packages with my own code. See https://github.com/kototama/.emacs.d